# Problem inheriting from ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, formsauthentication

I have a direct inheritance from ValidateUser ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider called CustomActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.

The only method that is overridden is ValidateUser.

When the custom provider is used everything work except that we can't find any users. GetAllUsers works but not FindUsersByName or EMail.

When we switch over to the original provider, with the same settings, everything starts to work.

Anyone got this problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the "FindUsersByName or EMail" methods and calling the base implementation explicitly?

I seem to recall guessing the method calls are made through introspection and assume an inheriting implementation